# Replacing laptop LCD panel

Tags: thinkpad, lcd, laptop-repair

I have a Lenovo T61 laptop. The LCD panel cracked recently.

I decided to try my hand at fixing it. I bought a replacement LCD on ebay http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=180399351582 for $85 shipped.

I opened the laptop, removed the old panel, installed the new one, and turned it on.

The Laptop boots fine, but the screen stays black. When I hook up an external display, that works.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you certain that the new panel works at all?  Basically there are two possibilities here - the panel is not correctly attached in the sense that something isn't seated properly, or something's wrong with it.  Third possibility is that you forgot to reconnect something - as long as the inverter card and cable are reinstalled that should be pretty much it, though.  Fourth possibility is that you damaged something but that's unlikely.

If the screen is unlit but you can make out an image with strong illumination your backlight isn't cutting on and probably the inverter isn't reinstalled properly.  (There also may be a bad backlight on the panel but that's unlikely.)

Comment: I hadn't plugged the connector in to the inverter properly. It was upside-down, but still went in far enough that I thought it was correct. Fixed that and now it looks great. http://twitpic.com/2c8rqw.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you; thankfully these things are pretty straightforward.