# Replacing laptop LCD screen

Tags: lcd, laptop-repair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacing laptop LCD panel](https://superuser.com/questions/172950/replacing-laptop-lcd-panel)

I have a basic Toshiba Satellite laptop, and its screen is apparently cracked. I can see colored lines or blots that are rapidly spreading. Is it easy to replace the LCD screen yourself?

Comment: Also http://superuser.com/questions/227546/replacing-the-lcd-panel-in-a-laptop, http://superuser.com/questions/118045/replacing-an-lcd-screen-in-a-laptop

Comment: I've removed the bit about suppliers to avoid this being closed as a shopping recommendation/subjective question.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the screen on a Dell Laptop.  It was very easy, requiring just a screwdriver and a deal of care keeping all of the screws in correct groups as they were of slightly different lengths.  For the Dell there is a decent online manual giving instructions on how to disassemble the case and where all of the connectors were hidden.  I do not know about the Toshiba laptop, but Google will probably help.

I cannot comment on your supplier as I have never used them.  I got my bits from a shop trading on eBay.